# SecurityException: Permission Denial ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS

Tags: java, android

I am trying to download files using DownloadManager. Yes I know people already got this error. but mine does not seems to be resolved. I have tried everytime.

I have decleared this permissions:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

My Code

```
public void startDownload(String str) {
    try {
        MarshmellowPermissions permissions = new MarshmellowPermissions(context);
        permissions.checkWriteExternalStoragePermission();
        DownloadManager mManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        DownloadManager.Request mRqRequest = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(str));
        mRqRequest.setDescription("This is Test File");
        long idDownLoad = mManager.enqueue(mRqRequest);
        mManager.remove(idDownLoad);
        try {
            mManager.openDownloadedFile(idDownLoad);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

I am getting error in this line

`mManager.openDownloadedFile(idDownLoad);`

this is the error log:

`java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider uri content://downloads/all_downloads/15 from pid=3926, uid=10086 requires android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS, or grantUriPermission()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look's like no one has an answer for this yet, I have already solved the issue and wanted to share how I solved it. So basically It wasn't working because I wasn't asking for permission on runtime.

What I did was ask the permission on runtime. Using this code below.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
```