# Getting java.lang.SecurityException: DownloadManager: Neither user 10173 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS

Tags: android, android-download-manager, android-9.0-pie

Getting this error in Android 9.0 while Downloading file using DownloadManager.

```
E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel                                                  
java.lang.SecurityException: DownloadManager: Neither user 10173 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS.
at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:1824)
at android.app.ContextImpl.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextImpl.java:1852)
at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider.query(DownloadProvider.java:918)
at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1074)
at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1166)
at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:246)
at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:102)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
```

i have Added "**android:networkSecurityConfig=@xml/network_security_config**" in the Manifest file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47361213/securityexception-permission-denial-access-all-downloads

Comment: yes but i have already granted permission for Storage. it seems to be another issue